# c# - Splitting a string with Email Id in it is truncating the last 3 characters of the Email

Tags: c#, string, winforms

I have a readonly textbox field which a value in it like 'Dan, Sealey - Dan.s42@KPS.com' , I want to retrieve the email id from the above string.

I tried using the below code

```
string email = Convert.ToString(this.txtUser).split('-')[1].Trim();
```

I even tried in the below way as well but no use, still the result is same.

```
string str = Convert.ToString(this.txtUser);
string trimmedString = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("-") + 1);
```

The issue i am having with the above line of code is it is truncating .com and giving the value as "Dan.s42@KPS..."

Not able to figure out why this is truncating ".com"

Any help on this ?

Comment: Are you saying it's adding an ellipsis to the value, three dots? Well, two dots I guess, if one of them was the one for ".com". Since the first code snippet returns exactly what you want, my guess is that you're putting the text in a label in the UI, which is truncating it for display.

Comment: its adding 4 dots

Comment: Make the label wider where you display `email`. Or is it a ListView column or a data grid column? It's something of that nature. Put in a breakpoint: `email` is the full email address. The ellipses are being added in the UI. You are doing nothing that could possibly be adding novel characters to that string.

Comment: If `txtUser` is a `TextBox`, then you want `txtUser.Text`, not `Convert.ToString(txtUser)`

Comment: Also, `Split` has a capital `S`. Please post the *actual* code that's not working.

Comment: So you would like to have the user name without the domain… then do var name=email.Split('@')[0]; to get the domain take var domain=email.Split('@')[1];

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is with `this.txtUser` text box. Debug what value is it returning. Check the max length or any limitation on length property. See if there's any masked control trimming the text based on length limitation.

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved, instead of `this.txtUser` i had to use `this.txtUser.text`